# How to avoid smooth and roundnes in my alpha brush when sculpting hard surface?

Tags: transparency, sculpting

Im totally a noob in sculpting with Blender, I want to use some alpha brushes to sculpt hard surfaces, I add a texture as a brush, select the texture under the sculpting brush, but when I use it it´s rounded and soften towards the corners (see picture).
This happen to me with every texture I try.

[image: Soft and rounded][image]

How can I make my brush harder and avoid this softnes?
Thank in advance to anyone who can help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, it was an oversight on my behalf, i just selected the straight "set brush shape" option in the "curve" tab
[image][image]